# Remove the space between arcs in Pie Chart, charts_flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, pie-chart

I am using the [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) package to display a Pie Chart. This is my code:

```
charts.PieChart<String>(
                        series,
                        animate: true,
                        defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                          strokeWidthPx: 0,
                          arcRendererDecorators: [
                            charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                              labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.inside,
                              labelPadding: 3,
                              showLeaderLines: false,
                              insideLabelStyleSpec: const charts.TextStyleSpec(color: charts.Color.white, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: "HelveticaRegular"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

However, I want to remove this padding between the arcs. Is it possible?

[image]